# How to Programmatically Add Items to Eclipse's Problems View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin where I need to add custom items to Eclipse's problems view. Custom items under maybe custom categories (for example list a bunch of problems under a category named "security").

I have looked into marker, but these are for file editors. I want to add custom items to the problems view without having to do anything with a source editor. Is that possible? Or do I have to create my own view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add the problem view to your plug-in.

```
org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create markers on Folders/Projects. You don't need to have a File to create a marker. The markers can be grouped via the type of Marker in the Problems View

Answer (score 0):

The Problems view only supports displaying markers.

Markers are associated with resources (usually files) but any plugin can create them, they don't have to done by editors.